# Javascript function call debug in browser

Tags: javascript, debugging

In my project i need to debug a function call in java-script. I need to know which part of my project calling this function in running time, how can i view using chrome browser development  tools

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `debugger` statement within your function (or use a breakpoint) and keep open Chrome debugger tool open. It works like using a breakpoint, at this point you can inspect the `Call Stack` where you can see where you function was called from.

If no debugging functionality is available (Chrome debugger tool is closed), this statement has no effect.

Example:

```
function yourCode() {
    debugger; // breakpoint here
}
```

More infos on debugging can be [found here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/?hl=en) and [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging).